# Deadlock Avoidance

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock

We have a huge batch process that updates XYZ table using other tables. This XYZ table is also used to store information entered from application UI. Now while this batch process is running, some user enters data from UI to go into XYZ table resulting in user transaction to be aborted.

ERROR:

> Msg 50000, Level 13, State 52, Procedure trgInsertBuilding, Line 101
>   Transaction (Process ID 65) was deadlocked on lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the
>   deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been
>   aborted.

Is there a way to get user data into DB while the batch is running?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without looking at the actual SQL why/where the deadlock happens. I assume that your batch process happens in one single long transaction. If a number of records is pretty huge, at some point (or if not from the beginning) the whole XYZ table is exclusively locked. It means that no other transaction can write into XYZ.

There is no simple solution to that, to solve this the whole design should be reconsidered. But what you can try is to use [Snapshot isolation level in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.110).aspx). This option would change SQL server concurrency mechanism from pessimistic to optimistic, allowing to simultaneously write into the same table (but not to the same rows).

But please note that this would affect the whole database and it must be thoroughly considered, researched and tested before pushing it into production use.